# How to transition using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get both the `<hr>` to transition but I'm limited to selecting only the lower `<hr>` using css.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

hr {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 5rem;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: center;
}

#expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
}

#expand:hover~hr {
  width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <hr>
  <div id="expand">
    Learn More
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Is there any anyway to make both the `<hr>` transition using simple javascript?
If not then which js library should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea is using pseudo elements instead of `<hr>`

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#expand:before,
#expand:after {
  content: '';
  width: 5rem;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  transition: width 1s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#expand:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#expand:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
}

#expand:hover:before,
#expand:hover:after{
  width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="expand">
    Learn More
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create an additional `wrapper` element, it can be done this way :-

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

hr {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 5rem;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: center;
}

#expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
}

#wrapper:hover>hr {
  width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="wrapper">
  <hr>
  <div id="expand">
    Learn More
  </div>
  <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, with this `#expand:hover~hr` you are selecting any general successor siblings of `#expand:hover` and in css there is no way to select previous siblings. To make the code work bring, down both `hr`'s into a common parent and apply the `hover hr` selector. In your case

codepen : https://codepen.io/pranaynailwal/pen/wvgwvea

Replace :

```
#expand:hover~hr {
  width: 20rem;
}
```

to :

```
#container:hover hr {
  width: 20rem;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, It didn't work. Can you send the complete code ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/pranaynailwal/pen/wvgwvea check this

Comment: sorry but this doesn't have the same effect desired. the hr expands when you hover over the container (white) but I need it to expand when hovering inside the expand (inner red)

Comment: hmm okay, then just add a wrapper div around it . i have update the code in  CodePen
https://codepen.io/pranaynailwal/pen/wvgwvea

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to style siblings backwards.

You could simply change

```css
#expand:hover~hr {
    width: 20rem;
}
```

to

```css
#container:hover hr {
    width: 20rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript you can add:

```
<script>
  const hrElements = document.querySelectorAll("hr");

  function addClass() {
    hrElements.forEach(el => el.setAttribute("class","bigger"))
  }

  function removeClass() {
    hrElements.forEach(el => el.setAttribute("class",""))
  }
<script>
```

**EDIT to clarify
include all of this css**

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

hr {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 5rem;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: center;
}

#expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
}

.bigger {
  width: 20rem;
}
```

then just edit the #expand div to include onmouseover and onmouseout linked to those functions; like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <hr />
  <div id="expand" onmouseover="addClass()" onmouseout="removeClass()">
    Learn More
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: nice approach but I asked for transition, the answer you've given has no transition effect see if you can modify accordingly

Comment: this is a transition effect. you include all of your css except the #expand:hover~hr block. and replace that with the class I added. That class is the change in the width and since you have transition width under the hr block in the css it will transition how you like it to. Do you need the whole css code or do you know what im saying?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify to show the original transition effect is just being applied everytime the .bigger class is added since it is a change in the width of the hr element. I made sure the whole thing worked in a codepen, and it transitions smoothly - not just immediate change in width.